# Refs in splitted onto 2 volumes book

Tags: cross-referencing

Suddenly I had to split the textbook I prepare, onto 2 volumes, to be published as separate books.

More or less I understand how to create separate table of contents with the package volumes, but my basic problem is to create proper references on different volumes.

Let imagine, I finish first volume, set mandatory counters to zero (page etc, maybe chapters also). And I have a lot of equations, math problems and references on them.

I need for the reference 
say, equation, to be

in the 1st vol:

(6.35), if it refers to the 1st volume, or
(II, 6.35) if eq. (6.35) sits in the 2nd volume

in the 2nd vol:

(6.35), if it refers to same (2nd) volume, or
(I, 6.35) if eq. (6.35) is located on the 1st volume

Here 6 means chapter -- the largest type of content. So I need some redefinitions with conditions, but in `\ref` and not in `\label`

The basic preamble is

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, openany]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=17cm, paperheight=220mm]{geometry}
\oddsidemargin=5mm \evensidemargin=5mm \frenchspacing

\textwidth=11.20cm \textheight=176mm
\usepackage{volumes}
\usepackage{booktabs}
```

Comment: See the `xr` ( `xr-hyper`, if you're using `hyperref`) package with its `\externaldocument` macro, in conjunction with `refcount`, perhaps:  such a fragment of code however is not useful at all

Comment: Is it really necessary to restart the chapter counting for the volumes?

Comment: No, the charter restart is still a point of consideration. I think, my question is independent of the chapter numeration in 2nd volume. The code fragment is given just to declare that I use book class.

Comment: I would suggest either \includeonly or the xr package.